# Get core Magento tables value in custom module

Tags: database

I want to fetch `productalert` table value in my custom module.

I tried below code.

```
$databae =  Mage::getModel('productalert/productalert')->load($alert_stock_id, 'alert_stock_id');
Mage::log( $databae );
```

`Warning: include(Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Productalert.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/somename/beta.somename.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93`

**UPdate::1**
I got the database now

```
$customer_id = 6;
$customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);

foreach ( $customer_stock_alerts as $alert ) {
    $customerValue =  $alert->getProductId();
}
```

**I want to send mail to all the user whose status=0 and a spacific product_id**

```
$customer_status = 0;
$customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_status)
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
```

But it gives me no data

Comment: Magento doesn't recognize `productalert` prefix for `getModel` factory. This means either you have incorrect configuration in `etc/config.xml` of your module or the module is not enabled.

Comment: i think it has to be `productalert/stock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code to collect data.

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')->load($alert_stock_id, 'alert_stock_id');
Mage::log( $databae );
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get all customer whose status = 0

Comment: i think i just need to change addFieldToFilter